# Unresolved reference: Kotlin needs 2 builds after clean to pick up code when using kapt

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin

In our Android app we're using [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow) to access the SQLite database. We're referencing the classes generated by DBFlow via Kotlin. We are already aware of the fact that we have the model classes as well as the database class in Java as code generation [won't work](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/596) when writing these classes in Kotlin.

However we still have to build the code twice after every project clean. Executing the first build on a device results in `ClassNotFoundExceptions` for seemingly random Kotlin classes (even if they don't access code generated by DBFlow or any of the model classes defined by us). The same is reported already at compile time when enabling Proguard which of course fails the build. The second build always succeeds.

The funny thing is, that code generation already works at the first run - the classes are there and are also picked up by the IDE. But the compiler somehow can't find them making me think that the code generation happens too late in the build process. On the other hand as explained above there are also classes not found which don't have to do anything with code generation and/or annotation processing.

So is there a better solution to this problem than a second build?

For reference, the relevant parts of our app's `build.gradle` looks like this - just like the [DBFlow documentation](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow#including-in-your-project) is suggesting:

```
def dbflow_version = "3.0.0-beta4"

dependencies {
    kapt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
}

kapt {
   generateStubs = true
}
```

**Edit:** I found that I also have to rebuild twice for every change I make to the code. It compiles correctly in the first build if I didn't clean before, but the changes simply aren't picked up.

Comment: Thought this could maybe be fixed by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8733, but unfortunately the fix doesn't seem to work when generateStubs is enabled.

Comment: i have exactly same issue with 1.0.5-2

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I want to generate the signed apks, I need to compile each buildType/flavor combination twice, which makes automated builds so much more unusable.

Comment: Have you managed to find the cause of the problem? Experiencing pretty similar issues with my current project :(

Comment: It seems to have been resolved. After several updates to Kotlin and the Android Studio plugin I just very seldomly have to build twice. I removed the generate stubs thingy though as it seems it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 8):

If you use kotlin and retrolambda this might fix it:

```
me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0
```

[github gist](https://gist.github.com/kibotu/fafd3047a46a7e838ab61a02804fb3ff)

Comment: No, we ditched retrolambda when making the move to Kotlin. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I'm applying kotlin to older projects which use retrolambda, so it is possible to use both as advertised.

Comment: omg this fixed all the weird issues I was having with Kotlin and Android. Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: I just had the exact same issue. I had to build twice for currentchanges to show up. Kind of wierdly, always the changes from the previous compile round showed up.

Do you have a link to the exact issue, I'm curious as to the reason why this happened.