# Android Studio doesn't compile changes until second compile with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I am compiling with Kotlin's puglin, I always have to run the project twice if I make a change, Android Studio does not recognize the change until it runs the project twice, Insnat Run its off and this continues happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're **not** using the latest Kotlin plug-in version (1.1.2-5 as of now) and/or Android Studio's latest stable version (2.3.3 as of now), then disabling Android Studio's Instant Run feature may **not** be able to fix this problem even though it's one of the most common solutions (based on blogs, SO posts here, and etc.) for properly running configuration changes to an app. Android Studio, particularly its alpha/beta versions (Alpha 4 as of now), are obviously bound to have buggy features, and the configuration-change bug could be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use kotlin and retrolambda this might fix it:

```
me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41076056/7861527